# Outgoing calls via SIP trunk

Tags: sip, asterisk, trunk, sip-server

I have one simple question which stuck me.
I have FreePBX server with SIP trunk to ISP. ISP Dedicated one PSTN number. So all internal SIP Extension go out with the same number. Does it mean that at any time just one Extension can call outside?

Thank you.
Best Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ask that question to your provider.

Usualy no limit, if no special limit on provider's side.

Comment: arheops Thank you for your reply. But I am still confused regarding unlimited number. How PSTN network can process unlimited number of calls from one Number at the same time. This is like dynamic NAT with one public IP can give access to Internet just one PC in a time. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: if you  connected via pstn,you have SINGLE port per single line(but still can have same number of 2 lines). Any digital connection can support any number on any "port". There are no any limit in network itself. Digital network can have 300lines capacity with same single number(connected via sip or 10x PRI E1 for example). So if you have "isp" which connected via plain lines,sure u will have limit. But even small providers most likly connected via network or pri.

Answer (score 0):

Just a hint. It would depend on your VoIP provider the number of simultaneous calls they allow you to do with one account, you can try SIP Trunk providers such as Switch2Voip [Call Center VoIP](http://switch2voip.us) they allow unlimited concurrent calls with very low rates.